# Get original element using .on

Tags: javascript, jquery

When using jQuery's event delegation, is there a way to retrieve the element on which .on was called, as well as the element on which the event was called?

**jQuery:**

```
$(".item").on("click","a",function() {
    var link = $(this); // a tag
    var itemDiv = // what?
});
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="item">
    <a href="#">Link</a>
    <a href="#">Link</a>
    <a href="#">Link</a>
    <a href="#">Link</a>
</div>
```

Comment: $(this).parent('div')

Comment: It's just its parent.

Comment: .parent would mean I query would have to *find* it and is inefficient. It has it stored already according to Christopher's answer. The example above is just that. It could be easily nested multiple times where .parent would not be feasible

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ...is there a way to retrieve the element on which .on was called, as
>   well as the element on which the event was called?

If you want to know which element the event is attached to you can use [**event.delegateTarget**](http://api.jquery.com/event.delegateTarget/).

You can use it similar to this:

```
$(".item").on("click", "a", function (event) {
    var link = $(this); // a tag
    var itemDiv = event.delegateTarget;
    console.log(itemDiv);
});
```

---

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/NQwea/) - Using event.delegateTarget

---

I'm not quite sure I understand the second part of the question but if you want to find out the exact element that initiated the event you can use [**event.target**](http://event.target).

I'm not sure this is what you meant but just in case I added an example below.

You may use it similar to this:

```
$(".item").on("click", "a", function (event) {
    var link = $(this); // a tag
    var initiatedBy = event.target;
    console.log(initiatedBy);
});
```

This comes in handy if you have, say a `span` inside your link or similar and need to inspect the exact element clicked on.

This can also come in handy if you want to attach an event to a container but not want to trigger any events inside it unless an exact element inside it was clicked.

---

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/ZDQJF/) - Inspecting the element which initiated the event (second link contains a `span`, see the difference in the console log)

---

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(".item").on("click","a",function() {
    var link = $(this); //the element on which the event was called
    var itemDiv = $(this).closest(".item"); //the element on which on was called
});
```

Comment: The code is just an example. .item may be nested multiple levels deep. I don't want to find it if I jquery already has a reference to it

Answer (score 0):

you can use the **.parent()** function ....

see this tutoriels links:

http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/traversing_parent.asp

http://coursesweb.net/jquery/jquery-parent-children-nth-child